# PowerPoint 2010 Chart Arrows

Tags: charts, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

Summary: I have a powerpoint slide that I created, that when played it changes the direction of the arrows.

Detail: I created a chart using Excel 2010 (Windows 7). I copied the chart and pasted it into PowerPoint 2010. It worked just fine and the directions of the arrows are correct (e.g. Marketing moves down and to the left). The problem is that when I hit f5 (or play the presentation) the arrows only go right.

Is there something wrong with what I am doing? I know I can fix it with a screenshot, but that is just a work around. Do you see the same thing that I am seeing?

[PowerPoint Slide](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/945626/extra%20slide.pptx)

Comment: Weird. I see it in PPT 2007 as well. If you reverse the beginning/end arrow endpoint styles, you get the reverse behaviour. I am guessing that the chart is getting confused between beginning and end points.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a scatter chart, you could try changing the order of the data points, so their order matches the order of the data points - but that's a complete guess.